# KVM and display trouble

Tags: windows-xp, kvm-switch

I just finished setting up a KVM between my computer (HP running WinXP) and my display. For some reason the screen has adjusted its settings and now there's something wrong, but I can't quite put my finger on what it is. I tried playing with the resolution settings but couldn't get to the point it was at before. Is there any place where the previous settings are saved so I can go back to them?

Comment: What KVM and what cables are you using to connect? Some KVMs might have a lower supported resolution than what you were running at before.

Comment: It's an Edimax EK-2U2C, connecting with USB and VGA cable. As far as I can tell the resolution now is the highest possible 1680x1050 on a Samsung 22 inch screen.